# Retrieve value of a input with (focus)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, focus

My Input looks like that :

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input 
    matInput 
    placeholder="A blablabla" 
    required 
    (focus)="focusIn($event)" 
    (focusout)="focusOut($event)" 
    [(ngModel)]="A.txt1" 
    (ngModelChange)="onChange()"
    (keypress)="numberOnlyMin($event)">
</mat-form-field>
```

My methods are :

```
focusIn(event: FocusEvent) {
  console.log(event.detail);
}

focusOut(event: FocusEvent) {
  console.log(event.detail);
}
```

Basically I want to retrieve the value of my input right after I finish writing, that is why I use `focusOut`.

However I retrieve 0 all the time, is there any reason why ?

And how to pass data between those 2 focus?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from the post, I believe your main intent is to actually know when the user has finished changing something in the input field and then use the value.

You could use the `(change)` event in order to know when something has changed in the field.

This will fire only once you've focused out of the input and there's a change in the input value. So you don't really have to listen to all those other events.

If you still want to be notified even if there's no change in the value of the input, using the `(blur)` event would be ideal.

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-change-value?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: This not not correct. (change) will only trigger if the value of the input changes. If you want to trigger on a "focusOut" event use (blur).

Comment: If it doesn't change, you shouldn't need to update your other input. The value will still be retained in ngModel, formControl, etcl; so the other input can still use it

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the blur-method.

Usage in Component:

```
  onBlur($event) {
    console.log($event.target.value);
  }
```

Usage in Markup

```
<input type="text" (blur)="onBlur($event)" >
```

Comment: Thanks I upvoted you for your correct answer as well !